# Как сгруппировать таблицу поминутно (почасово)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с полями

```
рынок,время,объём торгов
```

Как мне сгруппировать почасово каждый рынок с отображением торгов за данный час?
То-есть

```
Рынок1 в 12:00  1000
Рынок1 в 12:20  1100
Рынок1 в 12:50  1400
Рынок1 в 13:10  1450
Рынок2 в 12:00  300
```

В ответе я хочу получить

```
Рынок1  12:00  1400
Рынок1  13:00  1450
Рынок2  12:00  300
```

Либо по другому- состоянием на 12 часов на 13 часов.....

Comment: А как у вас выходит "на данный час" и при этом и 12 и 13 часов, какой час "данный" ?

Comment: Нужна сумма торгов за час или последнее из значений или ещё что-то?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так?

```
select market, DATEPART (hour,time) hour, SUM (value) as value
from table1
group by market, DATEPART (hour,time)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22323/4

Answer (score 1):

В запрос добавить GROUP BY hour(время) и далее по потребностям.

Comment: @"Ruslan Semenov" да, но запросов может быть десяток за один и тот же час, а я хочу сумарный- то есть с 12:00 по 12:59 - это что б была одна группировка

Comment: Да но что мешает сгруппировать сразу по нескольким данным, 1. рынки, 2 часы итп GROUP BY рынок, hour(время)

Comment: @"Ruslan Semenov" как мне прописать группировку по времени?

Comment: подобное здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604513/group-by-with-date-column-in-the-having-clause  , но мне не надо тупо указывать дату

Comment: SELECT date, sum(price)  FROM table GROUP BY year(date), month(date), day(date), customer